# Extracting image index from array in order to insert image into a bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of images which I can iterate over and display on my page however this is not what I want. I would like to find the index of each image in my array so that (on each loop) I can insert one of the images into my bootstrap carousel slides.

Will I need Javascript to do this? I am unsure and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

To start I tried to do a for each with index loop and extract the index but I was not able to :(

This is the bootstrap carousel. So far you can see that I have put my iteration into the first slide which means all 3 images are showing on the first slide:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <!--  <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(88).jpg"
       alt="First slide"> -->
      <!-- app/views/posts/show.html.erb -->
     <% if @service.images.attached? %>
      <% @service.images.each do |image| %>
        <%= image_tag(image) %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
     <div class="carousesl-item">
   <!--   <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(121).jpg"
    alt="Second slide"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
   <!--    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).jpg"
     alt="Third slide"> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Slides-->
  <!--Controls-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <!--/.Controls-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(88).jpg" width="100">
    </li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="1">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(121).jpg" width="100">
    </li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="2">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(31).jpg" width="100">
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
</div>
```

Comment: add your images to the html from your server side code and just initialize the slider why do you think you need to insert the images into the slider after the page has loaded ? are they coming from any ajax request or api ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam hmm well my images are uploaded by the user and the user can upload more than one image at a time. When the images are uploaded they are stored in ``@service.images`` so I am looking for a way to get the images from there and insert them into each slide on my carousel does that make sense?

Comment: yes that makes sense and that would require you to use javascript or jquery, i am more a `php` guy not familiar  with ruby so dont know if `@service.images` is a location that can be accessed via server side code? and return the urls of the images via ajax call to insert into the slider using javascript/jquery

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam ok i'm glad I was on the right path. I think what I need to do is a for each loop and then for each image i need to use JavaScript or something to insert each image into the carousel slide. The problem is I am a junior coder and I'm not sure how to write this yet. I'll wait for a bit longer to see if any other Rubyists know! Thank you. Also yes ``@service.images`` is the array that I am iterating over extract the image and display it to my FE.

Comment: you should check if the slider api provides you any method for adding a slide on runtime? if not, you might have to add child nodes in the parent container of the slider/carousel html and `destroy()` and then `initialize()` the slider again, most of the javascript libraries do provide an option to destrory the plugin

Comment: hey @MuhammadOmerAslam this is way over my head as im just a beginner. Is there no easier way to do this? I will research about the slider api and see what I find!

Comment: which slider are you using can you provide the link ?

Comment: Something similar to this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ the one that says "with indicators"

Comment: you just need to append the html to the `<div class="carousel-inner">`  and it will automatically pick it up no need to re-initialize or destroy it just prepare your html and use `$('.carousel-inner').append()` to add a new slide to the slider and it will pick it up automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198327/discussion-between-angela-inniss-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).